# Exception while inserting a record in to Apache Ignite Cluster using JDBC connection

Tags: java, insert, key, ignite

I've been struggling to run an insert query on Apache Ignite Cache using JDBC connection. I've created my Cache using the following configuration:

```java
CacheConfiguration<Long, MyApplication> cacheCfg = new CacheConfiguration<>("SQL_PUBLIC_MYAPPLICATION");
cacheCfg.setCacheMode(CacheMode.REPLICATED);
cacheCfg.setIndexedTypes(Long.class, MyApplication.class);
cacheCfg.setSqlSchema("PUBLIC");
cacheCfg.setCacheStoreFactory(FactoryBuilder.factoryOf(CacheMyApplicationStore.class));
cacheCfg.setReadThrough(true);
cacheCfg.setWriteThrough(true);
FifoEvictionPolicy<Long, MyApplication> eviction = new FifoEvictionPolicy<Long, MyApplication>();
eviction.setMaxSize(100_000);
IgniteCache<Long, MyApplication> cache = getIgnite().getOrCreateCache(cacheCfg);
cache.loadCache(null, 100_000);
```

#### MyApplication.java

```java
public class MyApplication {

    @QuerySqlField(index = true,orderedGroups = {@QuerySqlField.Group(name = "idx3", order = 0)})
    private Long ID;

    @QuerySqlField(index = true,orderedGroups = {@QuerySqlField.Group(name = "idx3", order = 1)})
    private String NAME;

    @QuerySqlField
    private String DESCRIPTION;
}
```

I was able to update or delete a record in the Cache using JDBC connection but the insert is not working. I'm getting an exception when I try to insert using the following code:

```java
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ignite:thin://url:4000");

try (PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement("insert into MyApplication (ID, NAME, DESCRIPTION) values (1, 'TestApp', 'To be deleted')")) {
    stmt.setLong(1, 1L);
    stmt.setString(2, "TestApp");
    stmt.setString(3, "To be deleted");
    stmt.executeUpdate();
}
```

#### Exception:

```
[17:15:14,894][ERROR][sql-connector-#58%agrid%][JdbcRequestHandler] Failed to execute SQL query [reqId=1, req=JdbcQueryExecuteRequest [schemaName=null, pageS ize=1024, maxRows=0, sqlQry=insert into MyApplication (ID, NAME, DESCRIPTION) values (?,?,?), args=[1, TestApp, To be deleted]]] class org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.IgniteSQLException: Failed to execute DML statement [stmt=insert into MyApplication (ID, NAME, DESCRIPTION) values (?,?,?), params=[1, TestApp, To be deleted]]]
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.IgniteH2Indexing.queryDistributedSqlFields(IgniteH2Indexing.java:1324)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.GridQueryProcessor$6.applyx(GridQueryProcessor.java:1856)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.GridQueryProcessor$6.applyx(GridQueryProcessor.java:1852)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.lang.IgniteOutClosureX.apply(IgniteOutClosureX.java:36)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.GridQueryProcessor.executeQuery(GridQueryProcessor.java:2293)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.GridQueryProcessor.querySqlFieldsNoCache(GridQueryProcessor.java:1860)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.odbc.jdbc.JdbcRequestHandler.executeQuery(JdbcRequestHandler.java:188)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.odbc.jdbc.JdbcRequestHandler.handle(JdbcRequestHandler.java:122)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.odbc.SqlListenerNioListener.onMessage(SqlListenerNioListener.java:152)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.odbc.SqlListenerNioListener.onMessage(SqlListenerNioListener.java:44)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioFilterChain$TailFilter.onMessageReceived(GridNioFilterChain.java:279)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioFilterAdapter.proceedMessageReceived(GridNioFilterAdapter.java:109)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioAsyncNotifyFilter$3.body(GridNioAsyncNotifyFilter.java:97)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:110)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.worker.GridWorkerPool$1.run(GridWorkerPool.java:70)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Key is missing from query
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.dml.UpdatePlanBuilder.createSupplier(UpdatePlanBuilder.java:331)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.dml.UpdatePlanBuilder.planForInsert(UpdatePlanBuilder.java:196)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.dml.UpdatePlanBuilder.planForStatement(UpdatePlanBuilder.java:82)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.DmlStatementsProcessor.getPlanForStatement(DmlStatementsProcessor.java:438)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.DmlStatementsProcessor.updateSqlFields(DmlStatementsProcessor.java:164)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.DmlStatementsProcessor.updateSqlFieldsDistributed(DmlStatementsProcessor.java:222)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.IgniteH2Indexing.queryDistributedSqlFields(IgniteH2Indexing.java:1321)
        ... 17 more
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just configure the cache and SQL indexes using [CREATE TABLE](https://apacheignite-sql.readme.io/docs/create-table) and [CREATE INDEX](https://apacheignite-sql.readme.io/docs/create-index) commands, especially, if you plan access Ignite with SQL operations mostly.

If key-value, computational or machine learning APIs are still required then check up [this project](https://github.com/dmagda/ignite_world_demo) that showcases how to do that when the caches are defined using SQL DDL commands.

Answer (score 1):

The root cause is the following:

```
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Key is missing from query
```

All the values you provided in the `INSERT` statement belong to value object, therefore Ignite fails to create a key object for the entry and throws this exception.

To fix this you should create a class for the key object (e.g. `MyApplicationKey`) and move `ID` field there.

Comment: I've tried to create a class for the key object (MyApplicationKey and AffinityKey). Both of them worked on first insert but the subsequent inserts are still failing but with a different reason:

Comment: Exception : err=class org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.IgniteSQLException: Duplicate key during INSERT [key=org.apache.ignite.cache.affinity.AffinityKey [idHash=20914538, hash=1]]]]. Looks like the hash is always been 1 when I insert a new record using JDBC drivers.